# Pandas - Filtering out dates by comparing two Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with list of days in a month as below:

```
Dataframe name : df

date
2018-12-01
2018-12-03
2018-12-07
2018-12-25
2018-12-31
```

I have another Dataframe with list of holidays:

```
Dataframe name : Holidays


date
2018-12-21
2018-12-25
```

I am trying to filter out dates in df that are present in Holidays using the below:

```
df = df[~df['date'].isin(Holidays['date'])]
```

The above should exclude `2018-12-25` from the final output but I see it still shows `2018-12-25` in the final dataframe.

Expected output:

```
Dataframe : df

date
2018-12-01
2018-12-03
2018-12-07
2018-12-31
```

Comment: add the code snippet to make it easier to debug and answer

Comment: The above code should work. Can you print out `df.dtypes` and `Holidays.dtypes`. If they are `object` it would also be useful to see the output of `df.date.unique()` versus `Holiday.date.unique()`, probably whitespace issues.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what you are already doing, but different.  I would just use logical indexing

```
idx = (df.date & Holidays.date)
df = df.loc[~idx, :]
```